# Unable to revoke admin consent for added permissions: Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-authentication, azure-ad-b2b

I have one Azure Ad app where I added permissions using `Add-AzADAppPermission`

To grant admin consent to these, I used CLI commands here

```
az login
az ad app permission admin-consent --id <application-id>
```

I can see admin consent is granted for these permissions in Portal:

[image]

But I want to remove this consent now from PowerShell.

Is there any command like `Revoke-AzADPermissionGrant` to achieve that?

I can do this from Portal, but I want it from PowerShell or CLI or Graph query.

Can anyone please shed light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To revoke **`admin_consent`** granted for Azure AD application permissions, you can make use of below **Graph API query**:

```
DELETE https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/oauth2PermissionGrants/<id>
```

To get the **`<id>`**, you can run this query by filtering it with **Service Principal ObjectID**.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/oauth2PermissionGrants/?$filter=clientId eq 'SP ObjectID'
```

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the below results:***

I created one **Azure AD application** and granted same **`API permissions`** like this:

[image]

You can get **`SP ObjectID`** of the above application like below:

***Go to Azure Portal -> Azure AD -> Enterprise Applications -> Your App -> Overview***

[image]

I ran the below query to get **`<id>`** by including **filter** like this:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/oauth2PermissionGrants/?$filter=clientId eq 'SP ObjectID'
```

**Response:**

[image]

I ran the **`DELETE`** query like below, I got the **response** successfully:

```
DELETE https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/oauth2PermissionGrants/<id>
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I checked Azure Portal, admin consent got **revoked successfully** for that application like below:

[image]

To do the same from **PowerShell**, try running below commands:

```
Connect-MgGraph
Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Identity.SignIns
Remove-MgOauth2PermissionGrant -OAuth2PermissionGrantId $Id
```

Make sure to install **`Microsoft.Graph`** module before running those commands.

If not, try using below command to **install** that module:

```
Install-Module Microsoft.Graph -Scope CurrentUser
```